# how to make horizontal scrollbar in dataview

Tags: html, css, sass, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have a primeng tableview currently styled with width: 100% and all the columns width is set in percentages, so if the data is long - the data is wrapped and there is a line break which makes the line becomes higher. 
I would like that in case a **specific** column has a data with lots of characters, an horizontal scroll-bar will appear at the bottom of the table view - allow us to scroll. How can I do it using css.
Here is my  (**simplified**):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-view-container">
    <p-dataView class="main-module-list" [rows]="pageSize" [totalRecords]='totalRecords'
        [paginator]="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"  [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)">
        <p-header>
            <div class="ui-g custom">
                <div class="ui-g20" data-field=''</div>
                <div class="ui-g30" data-field='' </i></div>
                <div class="ui-g40" data-field='' </div>
                <div class="ui-g10" data-field=''</i></div>
            </div>
        </p-header>
        <ng-template let-result pTemplate="listItem">
            <div class="list-item" >
                <div class="ui-g scroll custom">
                <div class="row ui-g20">{}</div> 
                <div class="row ui-g30">{</div>
                <div class="row ui-g40">{}</div> 
                <div class="row ui-g10">{{}</div> //In case that this column has long data, make the scrolbar
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dataView>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container
{
    width: auto;
    display: block;

    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    div.data-container
    {
        padding:2vw 2vw 1vw 2vw;
    }

    div.table-view-container
    {
        ::ng-deep p-dataView
        {
            p-header
            {
                div.ui-g
                {
                    margin-left: 17px; //For the left scrolbar
                }
            }
            div.ui-dataview.ui-widget.ui-dataview-list
            {
                div.ui-dataview-content
                {
                    overflow-y: auto;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
p-dataview
{
    div.ui-g.custom
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: .5em  0;
        div.row
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        div.ui-g10
        {
            width: 10%        
        }

        div.ui-g20
        {
            width: 20%;
        }
        div.ui-g30
        {
            width: 30%;
        }
        div.ui-g40
        {
             width: 40%;
        }
        div.auto-width
        {
            width: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add `overflow-x: scroll;` to your css it will do the trick if im right

Comment: @xmaster - did so as default solution - this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Put DataGrid inside ScrollViewer tag then set Height, Width etc. Code sample as shown below.

```
 <Grid>
           <GroupBox>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                   <ScrollViewer  Width="500" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Foreground="Red">
                       <DataGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                           <DataGrid.Columns>
                           </DataGrid.Columns>
                       </DataGrid>
                   </ScrollViewer>
               </StackPanel>
           </GroupBox>

       </Grid>
```